# chrome installation on centos linux using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, google-chrome

I am installing google Chrome web browser on my centos VM by writing a shell script to do so. I have downloaded the following :

> google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm

And when I try to install this package I get the following error:

> warning: google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 7fac5991: NOKEY
>   error: Failed dependencies:
>       lsb >= 4.0 is needed by google-chrome-stable-58.0.3029.110-1.x86_64
>       libnss3.so(NSS_3.19.1)(64bit) is needed by google-chrome-stable-58.0.3029.110-1.x86_64
>       libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.18)(64bit) is needed by google-chrome-stable-58.0.3029.110-1.x86_64
>       libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.14)(64bit) is needed by google-chrome-stable-58.0.3029.110-1.x86_64
>       libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) is needed by google-chrome-stable-58.0.3029.110-1.x86_64

I realized that I should download many different packages before that I can install Chrome.
Is there any way to install these packages all together without having to install them one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Using yum command to install Chrome Browser on the Centos system.

```
yum localinstall google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [this](https://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/) to add the source for Chrome